# How to paint a gradient color in Android on a Canvas with the color changing?

Tags: android, canvas, gradient, shader

I need to paint the background of my Canvas one color with shading/gradient applied, but each onDraw call I would like to potentially change the color.

I am having trouble doing this without creating a new object each onDraw call. Anyone have any ideas?  If I use drawPaint() and set a new shader() to my paint, then I have created a new shader object and if I create a new GradientDrawable() I have as well.  I want to avoid GC.

I thought I could reuse one GradientDrawable() object and call the .setColor() method, but this just resets any gradient data associated it and paints the drawable as that solid color.

Anyone?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately you have to create a new LinearGradient everytime. Note that you don't have to use a GradientDrawable, you can draw the shape yourself with a Paint on which you set the shader.

Comment: Thanks Romain, could you share you expertise in my comment to campnic below?  I am wondering what the most efficient .draw...() method would be to either draw the two layers required to create this effect or if LayerDrawable is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Romain Guy I've been trying to use SweepGradient to achieve conical gradient effect. But it seems to work only with two colors. If I use a four color array then **SweepGradient** doesn't seem to work as expected. I tried various combinations of **positions** values and also tried settings positions as **NULL** but most of the I'm getting only two colors or a gradient which is not conical. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is this.  Create a LayerDrawable and then insert two Drawables into it.  The first Drawable you insert should have its color set to the color you'd like your background to be and the second should be a Gradient that is set up to be black and transition from alpha 0 to alpha 255.

For more information, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

Comment: campnic - thanks this is kind of what I was going for when I thought to call canvas.drawARGB() with alpha xFF and then a paint w/ shader or gradient with lesser alpha on top of it.  I am just worried about efficiency.  I wanted to avoid drawing the entire canvas with two layers and wanted to know if there was a built in construct to do this in one go.  Does the LayerDrawable achieve this or does it actually do sequential drawing layer by layer?

Comment: I did a bit of digging, and what I'm seeing suggests that you'd end up drawing two full layers across the entire screen.  The code for LayerDrawable.draw just iterates over the child Drawables in descending index order.  I think the performance of the LayerDRawable may not be what you want to use.  Romain has a lot more experience with this stuff, so he can probably give you a better idea :)

Comment: I really appreciate you looking to this - this is what I also found and suspected when looking over the documentation.  I'll have to think of something creative for a nice dynamic looking background if there is no built in solution.

Answer (score 0):

This question is still valid almost in the middle of 2017. I wanted to create a smooth transition for color changes for my custom view. I used shaders with LinearGradients.

My intention was to make a smooth transition betweeen anabled and disabled state of my view.

My case is even more complicated due to construction and purpose of the view. It's a slider. So my view consists of almost 2 identical layers drawn one on top of the second one using canvas. Third element is a pointer.

Both layers use LinearGradients, pointer use a single color.

Summing all I have to do a transition between 5 colors at the same time:

- start and end color for bottom layer - one LinearGradient,
- start and end color for top layer - second LinearGradient,
- pointer color - normal color;

Solution to this is to have 5 separate ValueAnimators. The most important thing is to use ValueAnimator.ofArgb():

```
private ValueAnimator frontStartColorAnimator;
private ValueAnimator frontEndColorAnimator;
private ValueAnimator bottomStartColorAnimator;
private ValueAnimator bottomEndColorAnimator;
private ValueAnimator pointerColorAnimator;
private AnimatorSet colorsAnimatorSet;

...

frontStartColorAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(frontLayerStartColor, frontLayerDisabledStartColor);
frontStartColorAnimator.setDuration(animationDuration);
frontStartColorAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
frontStartColorAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation
            -> shaderFrontLayerStartColor = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue());

frontEndColorAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(frontLayerEndColor, frontLayerDisabledEndColor);
frontEndColorAnimator.setDuration(animationDuration);
frontEndColorAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
frontEndColorAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
        shaderFrontLayerEndColor = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        frontLayerPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, getWidth(), 0, shaderFrontLayerStartColor,
                shaderFrontLayerEndColor, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
    });

bottomStartColorAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(bottomLayerStartColor, bottomLayerDisabledStartColor);
bottomStartColorAnimator.setDuration(animationDuration);
bottomStartColorAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
bottomStartColorAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation ->
            shaderBottomLayerStartColor = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue());

bottomEndColorAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(bottomLayerEndColor, bottomLayerDisabledEndColor);
bottomEndColorAnimator.setDuration(animationDuration);
bottomEndColorAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
bottomEndColorAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
        shaderBottomLayerEndColor = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        backLayerPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), shaderBottomLayerStartColor,
                shaderBottomLayerEndColor, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
    });

pointerColorAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(pointerEnabledColor, pointerDisabledColor);
pointerColorAnimator.setDuration(animationDuration);
pointerColorAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
pointerColorAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
        pointerColor = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        pointerPaint.setColor(pointerColor);
    });

colorsAnimatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
colorsAnimatorSet.playTogether(frontStartColorAnimator, frontEndColorAnimator,
            bottomStartColorAnimator, bottomEndColorAnimator, pointerColorAnimator);

...

colorsAnimatorSet.start();
```

I also was concerned at start about creating a new LinearGradient on each animation update but then I launched GPU profiling on device with "On screen as bars". Everything is fine and running within safe margin.